# Filling form with Jquery click function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a GUI to let the user edit any row that is displayed in my table. I've manage to create a form that pops up when the user clicks an image which symbolize an edit icon. Now I like to use Jquery (if possible) to fill this form with data from my DB. The error code is down bellow and I can't seem to get any results at all

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#edit').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'edit.php?itemid=$itemid',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#itemid').val($itemid);
                ......
                $('#status').val($status);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edit.php**

```
<?php
$DB = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "book1");
$result2 = mysqli_query($DB, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE itemID='$itemid'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
    $itemid = $row['itemID'];
    ......
    $status = $row['status'];
}
echo (array($itemid, $userid, $description, $manufacturer, $model, $caldate, $duedate, $shelf, $status);
?>
```

**Form**

```
<div id="light1" class="white_content">
            <form id="editform" name="myForm" action="checkout.php" method="POST">
                <h2>Edit Instrument</h2>
                <label>ItemID:</label> 
                <input type="text" id="itemid"/>
                <br>
                ......
                <a>Status: </a>
                <input type="text" id="status"/>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Accept">
                <input href = "javascript:void(1)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" type="reset" value="Close">
                <br>
            </form>
        </div>
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: $itemid is not defined

   $('#itemid').val($itemid);
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
  $('#itemid').val($itemid);
```

to

```
  $('#itemid').val('<?php echo $itemid; ?>');
```

Comment: error: unterminated string literal $('#itemid').val('<br />

Comment: your content has some problem it must be having special characters that are creating problem